# My Google image ad is consistently receiving 0 impressions

Tags: google, images, google-ads

I set up my first Google image ad two days ago. It was approved almost immediately, but I have seen 0 impressions and 0 clicks since then.

I tried setting my CPC to $4, which I figured should be high enough to win bids at lease *some* of the time, but no luck.

Anyone experienced this? My text ads continue to receive impressions but after two and a half days I still see nothing for the image ad.

Comment: Are you bidding on competitive keywords?

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing an image ad it's not going to trigger results within Google Search Partners, only on the Content Network, so it could be that the keyword(s) you're bidding on just don't have any real volume, which happens quite a bit.

You also need to check under the keywords tab to see if the ads are eligible to show. There is a little icon that allows you to see the quality score and it should say that the ad is in fact live.

I'd suggest focusing on text ads since they have proven that they have higher performance and relevance than image ads.